# Is $x^y=y^x$ an equivalence relation in $R^+$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have verified that the first two properties of the equivalence relation: reflexivity and symmetricity are obeyed, and they are trivial. But I have some doubt about the third, the transitivity.
From transitivity, I think $x^y=y^x$ isn't an equivalence relation. Am I right?

Comment: The condition is equivalent to $x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}$, at least if the numbers you have in mind are positive. (If they're not, how in general do you define exponentiation?) In that case, it's trivially an equivalence relation.

Comment: Are you restricting $y$ and $x$ to positive numbers?

Comment: Please excuse me , yes $R^+$

Comment: @J.G. please look at the definition

Comment: @J.G. I don't see why it's trivially transitive

Comment: @David It's transitive because there exists a function $f : \Bbb{R}^+ \to S$, where $S$ is some set $S$, such that $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$. In this case, $f(x) = x^{1/x}$. So, if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$, then $f(x) = f(y) = f(z)$, which implies $x \sim z$. This might be considered "trivial" by J.G, but it's worth noting that every equivalence relation admits many such functions.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for confirming a restriction to $\Bbb R^+$. If $x^y=y^x$ and $y^z=z^y$, $x^{1/x}=y^{1/y}$ and $y^{1/y}=z^{1/z}$, so $x^{1/x}=z^{1/z}$ and $x^z=z^x$.